# Using a default image file path for uploading image in java app

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, filenotfoundexception

So, I need so clarity as to what I am overlooking when it comes to attempting to set a default image file path if a user selects no image. I utilized `JFileChooser` in a browse button in order to get the image path (relative path, not absolute) in order to store the image path on a `MySQL` database.

The problem is with my `imageFileUploader` class. I am attempting to set a generic image as a default if the user does not want to upload an image. When I test my imageFileUploader class, I am getting a null pointer exception. I essentially have the text box saying "no file uploaded" and if this stays true, then it uploads the default image. Can someone put an eye on my code and provide me some points to anything that I am overlooking? I would be much obliged.

```
String imagePath = "";
            byte[] rawBytes = null;
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

            if(imagePath.equals("No File Uploaded")) {//null pointer exeception here!!
                ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
                URL resources = classLoader.getResource("/abaApplicationImages/blankProfile.jpg");
                imagePath = resources.getFile();
            }else{
                //File fileObject = new File(imagePath);

            File fileObject = new File(imagePath);

            try {
                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileObject);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("file not found");
            }

            int imageLength = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(fileObject.length()));
            rawBytes = new byte[imageLength];
            try {
                fileInputStream.read(rawBytes, 0, imageLength);
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("IO exception");

            }


        }
            return imagePath;
        }
```

Error message:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native
>   Method) at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source) at
>   abaApplication.ImageUploader.ImageUploader(ImageUploader.java:30) at
>   abaApplication.ImageUploader.main(ImageUploader.java:59) file not
>   found Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   abaApplication.ImageUploader.ImageUploader(ImageUploader.java:40) at
>   abaApplication.ImageUploader.main(ImageUploader.java:59)

Comment: Post the exception message too

Comment: For anyone curious, this is the exception message that I am getting when the program is run.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at abaApplication.ImageUploader.ImageUploader(ImageUploader.java:30)
 at abaApplication.ImageUploader.main(ImageUploader.java:59)
file not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at abaApplication.ImageUploader.ImageUploader(ImageUploader.java:40)
 at abaApplication.ImageUploader.main(ImageUploader.java:59)

Comment: So, essentially java:30 is the fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileObject), java 40: is fileInputStream.read(rawByte, 0, imageLength.

Answer (score 1):

You're not verifying if the `URL resources` is null or not. That's probably where the NPE is coming from.

Also `ClassLoader.getResource()` loads resource from the classpath, if the file is on the image file is not on classpath then you should probably use `FileInputStream` directly.

Comment: @11dimension, my thought was that the default image would go in the classpath or relative path for default image storage. Or am I going about that the wrong way? And can you elaborate a bit more about the URL resources being null?

Comment: If the `getResource()` can't find the resource it returns null. This is probably the cause of NPE, as it can't find the path so the `resources.getFile()` generates NPE. If the file is on the classpath then it's alright to use this method. Otherwise use the normal FileIO methods. Normally `getResource()` is used to read files inside the packed JAR or WAR file.

Comment: Right on. Thanks for the input. I'll read up in more detail about the getResource and ClassLoader. I am assuming I over looked something when reading about them, as my logic seems to be a bit off. Much appreciated!